# Atom editor: add parameter to command in menu

Tags: atom-editor

I'm dynamically adding several menu items by doing a loop and adding it like this:

```
{label: entry.getBaseName(), command: 'mymodule:openproj'}
```

This works, and calls a function previously defined:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
  'mymodule:openproj': (event) ->
    console.log event
```

But what I need to do is pass a parameter to the function, since I want my command to do something different based on which menu item is clicked. I'm thinking I'd call it as:

```
{label: entry.getBaseName(), command: 'mymodule:openproj('+entry.getBaseName()+')'}
```

But that doesn't call the function.

Answer (score 0):

The input for [MenuManager::add](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.11/MenuManager#instance-add) defines that the *command* attribute is a string, and that is a reference to the *commandName* attribute in [CommandRegistry::add](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.11/CommandRegistry#instance-add) which is just a name and not a JavaScript expression.

However, the callback function attached to the command is invoked with the DOM node (menu item) as the `this` reference. So, if you use a single *commandName* for multiple menu items, you can use that to identify which menu item was clicked and act accordingly.

Comment: Do you know how I could access the menu item that I clicked on? I change the code above to this: `atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
  'mymodule:openproj': (event) ->
    console.log this` but it prints out the whole atom-workspace node, not just the menu item.